# How to solve the "Cross-thread operation not valid" Problem?

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a windows forms dialog, where a longer operation is running (asynchron) within a **backgroundworker** job. During this operation I want to change some values on the form (labels,...). But when the backgroundworker tries to change something on the form, I get the error "**Cross-thread operation not valid**"! How can this problem be solved ?

Comment: This is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993020

Comment: Better to start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089
At the beginning of the series!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `ReportProgress` method from the worker, and handle the `ProgressChanged` to update the current state.

Answer (score 2):

Check if invoke is required, then call BeginInvoke.

```
private void AdjustControls()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.AdjustControls));
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "Whatever";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried this. But it doesn't work. Can yu give me more details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry my bad, I fixed it up a bit. If AdjustControls takes parameters, for example, if it is an event handler, then you cannot use MethodInvoker, you have to define a delegate for it.

Answer (score 1):

I feel a little weird tooting my own horn here, but you may find some use from the [**ThreadSafeControls**](http://threadsafecontrols.codeplex.com/) library I wrote for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change controls directly inside a thread which did not create them. You can use an invoke method as shown above, or you can use the BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged event.

**Code used inside BackgroundWorker DoWork:**

```
myBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(50); // Report that the background worker has got to 50% of completing its operations.
```

**Code used inside BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged:**

```
progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; // Change a progressbar on the WinForm
```